# Mailman 2.1.12 - disable user passwords and listserv commands

Tags: mailman

Using Mailman version: 2.1.12

I'm looking for a way to do several things with Mailman:

1. Disable user passwords completely.  I know how to disable the reminders, but I'd like for them not to be set via e-mail or other sources.  My concern is that a user will use a personal password and Mailman does not secure this at all.
2. Disable LISTSERV commands (such as SUBSCRIBE, etc) via e-mail.

My plan is to replace the web interface with an alternative system, or write a simpler list management front-end with LDAP authentication using CherryPy+Apache at some point.

Comment: Don't disable the ability of people to unsubscribe, unless you want to find yourself blacklisted as a spammer.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the password is only used in the webfrontend, so if you're replacing that, you don't need to worry about passwords.

And if you don't add the relevant aliases (foo-subscribe@...) to your mailserver, those commands don't happen either.

Answer (score 0):

If using mailman is not a requirement then you should consider sympa.

Sympa does not have this old school thinking with passwords and mail commands and has a nice web GUI. It has several integration strategy with LDAP.

http://www.sympa.org/doc/index